# IBM JVM 1.6 SR14: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fontmanager (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)

Tags: java, aix, ibm-jdk, ibm-jvm

We upgraded IBM Java on our AIX machine from Java 1.6 SR 9 to Java 1.6 SR14 and now we have following error during start of our applications:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fontmanager (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1030)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:994)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:507)
        at sun.font.FontManager$1.run(FontManager.java:240)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:273)
        at sun.font.FontManager.<clinit>(FontManager.java:235)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.isComplexLayout(SwingUtilities2.java:203)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:736)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:704)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFReader$DocumentDestination.deliverText(RTFReader.java:1610)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFReader$TextHandlingDestination.handleText(RTFReader.java:1546)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFReader.handleText(RTFReader.java:186)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFParser.write(RTFParser.java:163)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.AbstractFilter.readFromReader(AbstractFilter.java:116)
        at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit.read(RTFEditorKit.java:122)
        at Rtf.convert(Rtf.java:17)
        at Rtf.main(Rtf.java:29)
```

Following code allows to reproduce this problem:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class Rtf {

        public Rtf() {
        }

        static public String convert(String rtf) throws Exception {
                DefaultStyledDocument styledDoc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
                RTFEditorKit rtfKit = new RTFEditorKit();
                StringReader reader = null;
                reader = new StringReader(rtf);
                rtfKit.read(reader, styledDoc, 0);
                Document doc = styledDoc.getDefaultRootElement().getDocument();
                String txt = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                return txt;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                System.getProperties().store(System.out, "Current System props");

                System.out.println("fontmanger LIB: "+ System.mapLibraryName("fontmanager"));

                String rtf="{\\rtf1\\deff0{\\fonttbl{\\f0 Times New Roman;}{\\f1 Courier New;}}{\\colortbl\\red0\\green0\\blue0 ;\\red0\\green0\\blue255 ;}{\\*\\listoverridetable}{\\stylesheet {\\ql\\f1\\fs2
0\\cf0 Normal;}{\\*\\cs1\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 Default Paragraph Font;}{\\*\\cs2\\sbasedon1\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 Line Number;}{\\*\\cs3\\ul\\f1\\fs20\\cf1 Hyperlink;}}\\sectd\\pard\\plain\\ql{\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 draw 2 extra
 6ml lav. label with chart labels\"}\\f1\\fs20\\par\\pard\\plain\\ql{\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 ?When to Transfuse: When Avl}\\f1\\fs20\\par}";
                String txt = Rtf.convert(rtf);
        }
}
```

There are no any exceptions if to run Rtf class without any jvm arguments:

```
java Rtf
```

But if to run Rtf class with **"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"** jvm argument then there will be exception **"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fontmanager (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)"**:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote Rtf
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to add the directory /usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/xawt to current LIBPATH.