# cannot use pdfbox from websphere liberty

Tags: java, pdfbox, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to use pdfbox from Websphere Liberty.
trying the basic hello world in simple java application, it worked just fine,

Added all the jars to my liberty runtime, then trying the same code 
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            ....

the first line is working just fine, but when trying to create the PDPage I got the following exception

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: awt (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)

it looks like something is missing but I cannot see what, may be I'm just blind, I wonder if anyone can suggest anything to try ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read this? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21671811 and this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641734 and this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588932

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224511/ibm-jvm-1-6-sr14-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-fontmanager-not-found-in-com and this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV52311 . You will probably need to add correct directory to current LIBPATH.

Comment: thanks all, but I don't think this is the same case. after some investigation, didn't fix the problem yet, but I found that awt doesn't work from liberty. so even without PDFBox, just create new instance of java.awt.Color get the same error. still investigating